# Run only the button that was clicked

Tags: angular, typescript

I developed two buttons that change the text when they are clicked.
My problem is that when I click on one of them, all the others change too :(

What should I do to just change the text the button that was clicked?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gggyko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**HTML**

```
<div class="Submitcomments" *ngFor="let c of data; let  i = index;">
    <div>
        <div class="row rowComments" style="margin-top: 11px;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control AreaText" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 5px;">
            <button *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" class="btn reply" (click)="currentState='start' ; Execute(i)">Yes</button>
            <button *ngIf="currentState=='start'" class="btn reply1" (click)="currentState='pause'; Execute(i)">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You use a single currentState variable to hold the state of several buttons. That can't possible work. You need one variable per button. So, either a parallel array, or a property of each element of data, or a separate component per element of data

Comment: My idea was to use the index, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Well... make it work then. I can't help you fix the error if you don't post the code you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Extracting the comments code in a separate component would be a better idea as it would reduce the complexity and also make the template leaner. But again, it is a debatable topic.

If you want to don't want to extract the comment as component, then you should maintain separate variables to hold data of each comment:

```
data = [
    {    
        ID:1,
        Name : "Name",
        currentState: "pause"
    },
    {    
        ID:2,
        Name : "Name2",
        currentState: "pause"
    },
       {    
        ID:3,
        Name : "Name3",
        currentState: "pause"
    },
       {    
        ID:4,
        Name : "Name4",
        currentState: "pause"
    },
  ];
```

Then, in the HTML, you could do something like:

```
<div class="Submitcomments" *ngFor="let c of data; let  i = index;">
    <div>
        <div class="row rowComments" style="margin-top: 11px;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control AreaText" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 5px;">
            <button *ngIf="c.currentState=='pause'" class="btn reply" (click)="c.currentState='start' ; Execute(i)">Yes</button>
            <button *ngIf="c.currentState=='start'" class="btn reply1" (click)="c.currentState='pause'; Execute(i)">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Another approach would be to maintain a separate array to hold the states, if you don't want to modify the incoming object array.

```js
currentStates = [
    "pause",
    "pause",
    "pause",
    "pause"
  ]

   data = [
    {    
        ID:1,
        Name : "Name"
    },
    {    
        ID:2,
        Name : "Name2"
    },
       {    
        ID:3,
        Name : "Name3"
    },
       {    
        ID:4,
        Name : "Name4"
    },
  ];
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div class="Submitcomments" *ngFor="let c of data; let  i = index;">
    <div>
        <div class="row rowComments" style="margin-top: 11px;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control AreaText" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 5px;">
            <button *ngIf="currentStates[i]=='pause'" class="btn reply" (click)="currentStates[i]='start' ; Execute(i)">Yes</button>
            <button *ngIf="currentStates[i]=='start'" class="btn reply1" (click)="currentStates[i]='pause'; Execute(i)">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works, but I didn't want to add the currentState to the object :(

Comment: So, what is your requirement?

Comment: It is not possible to get this to work without using currentState in dataSource, so it worked for all cases, not depending directly on what comes in the data source.

Comment: Well, in that case, you can maintain a separate array for the states and use the index to manipulate the states.

Comment: Course it's possible. I already geve you 3 options in my comment. A fourth one would be to wrap every object in a wrapper which has a currentState property.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried to use index, because in my mind it made more sense, but it doesn't work correctly. I think the link should be updated with what I tried, I will see what is wrong and try new ways

Comment: If we want to use a wrapper then extracting the `comment` as a separate component would be more convenient as that would allow us to add more properties as that would help in keeping containers' `component.ts` cleaner.

Comment: I don't see anything changed. You still have a single currentState variable. You need as many such variables as there are elements in the array, since every element has its own state.

Comment: @VighneshRaut 
I am thinking of solving this by sending the state inside the object through the service ... that was the only way it could work, I could not get it any other way

Comment: That, I guess, would complicate things for no good. But again, I am not able to clearly understand your concern. Please update the code on stackblitz so we can analyze it further.